# how to get intersection between two moving resources in AnyLogic model

Tags: anylogic

i have model of site layout which has different resources moving at different time using the same path, and i need to get intersection between them during moving in the path.

Having a code let me able to trace the current location of each moving resource and another code to count when the location of two resources are the same at the same time.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help